# R -- Use List value to lookup and return value from datafarme

Tags: r, list, lookup

I do not want to loop if I don't have to!

I am trying to iterate through a list, for each value in the list I want to lookup that value in a dataframe and pull data from another column (like a vlookup).  I did my best to explain more detail in me code below.

```
# Create First dataframe
df = data.frame(Letter=c("a","b","c"),
               Food=c("Apple","Bannana","Carrot"))

# Create Second dataframe
df1 = data.frame(Testing=c("ab","abc","c"))

# Create Function               
SplitAndCalc <- function(i,dat){
  # Split into characters 
  EachCharacter <- strsplit(as.character(dat$Testing), "")  

  # Iterate through Each Character, look up the matching Letter in df, pull back Food from df

  # In the end df1 will looks something like Testing=c("ab","abc","c"), Food=c("Apple","AppleBannanaCarrot","Carrot")

  return(Food)
}

library("parallel")
library("snow")

# Detect the number of CPU cores on local workstation
num.cores <- detectCores()

# Create cluster on local host
cl <- makeCluster(num.cores, type="SOCK")

# Get count of rows in dataframe
row.cnt = nrow(df1)

# Call function in parallel
system.time(Weight <- parLapply(cl, c(1:row.cnt), SplitAndCalc, dat=df1))

# Create new column in dataframe to store results from function
df1$Food <- NA

# Unlist the Weight to fill out dataframe
df1$Food <- as.numeric(unlist(Weight))
```

Thanks!

Comment: so "ab" would match foods with "a" and "b", regardless of order, similarly for other combinations?

Comment: I want to split out each value, so I don't want to look at "ab", I want to look at "a" and bring back a value, then look at "b" and bring back a value.  So "ab" would bring back "AppleBannana" and "ba" would bring back "BannanaApple".  Hope that helps.

Comment: Please comment even if you don't have the full answer, maybe it will get me (or others here) on the right path.  This is big for me and I am stuck. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something that will work for me, posting incase it can help someone else...

```
# Create First dataframe
df = data.frame(Letter=c("a","b","c"),
               Food=c("Apple","Bannana","Carrot"))

# Create Second dataframe
df1 = data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),
  Testing=c("ab","abc","a","cc","abcabcabc"))

# Split into individual characters 
EachCharacter <- strsplit(as.character(df1$Testing), "")

# Set the names of list values to df1$ID so we can merge back together later
temp <- setNames(EachCharacter,df1$ID)

# Unlist temp list and rep ID for each letter
out.dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(names(temp), sapply(temp, length)),
                      Letter = unlist(temp))

# Merge Individual letter weight
PullInLetterFood <- (merge(df, out.dat, by = 'Letter'))
```